# Executing shell commands from SSDT Post Deploy scripts to generate SQL

Tags: sqlcmd, merge, ssdt

**tl;dr:** I'm looking for the equivilant of `!! sqlcmd -S $(Server) -o foo.sql -d $database -Q "EXEC sp_generate_merge 'table_name'"` in a SSDT post deploy script, but `!!` doesn't seem to be supported.

I have a SSDT database project with tables of "static data" that I populate via MERGE statements in the post deploy script. Many of these tables are reverse engineered from   I found [this article](https://dataonwheels.wordpress.com/2013/03/06/steps-to-preload-data-into-tables-with-ssdt/) about using `:r foo.sql`to have multiple files for post deploy.

I'd like to take this another step. I'd like generate the the merge statement by calling `sp_generate_merge` from a reference database on a remote server, and then executing the resulting merge statement on my database. I could use `!! SHELL_CMD` in sqlcmd or SSMS with SQLCMD mode enables, but that does not work in SSDT. What are my options?